# reverse in between values of first and last index of list with list slicing

Tags: python-3.6

I tried to slicing in between values of first and last of list. Can anyone explain following code.
where **index jump** value effecting the list and giving output, if i don't mention **index jump** value its giving empty list.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

l[5:-7:-1]

output :- [6, 5, 4, 3, 2] # This is the exact output what i want.

l[5:-7]

output :- []
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, "-1" means in reverse direction (right-to-left).

So, l[5:-7:-1] is equivalent to l[5:0:-1]. (-7 from last index is 0)

Hence it prints all values from index 5 to index 0 in reverse direction with 1 jump.

Similarly, l[5:-7] is equivalent to l[5:0] (default jump is +1).
Since no item is present between index 5 and index 0 (left-to-right direction), hence empty list is returned.